# WcfTestClient takes in parameters returns null

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using wsfTestClient to debug a c# wcf service program. my interface for this function has

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "AddCsv?fileLoc={fileLoc}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void AddCsv(string fileLoc);
```

and the corresponding class is

```
     public void AddCsv(string fileLoc)
    {
        List<Entity> listOfEntries = LoadCSV(fileLoc);
        PutList(listOfEntries);

    }
```

I have a breakpoint at the declaration of the AddCsv method and I look at the fileLoc variable and it is null. Why is this acting this way? fileLoc is a directory location.

Here is a screen shot of the wcftestclient

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you passing a value? Can you share a screenshot of WcfTestClient?

Comment: Sorry apparently I am short some reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF Test Client does not work for non-SOAP endpoints (a.k.a. WCF REST services). Since you decorated your operation with [WebGet] I'm assuming this is the case for you. The issue is that non-SOAP endpoints do not expose their metadata so that tools such as WCF Test Client (or svcutil) can know how to call the service.

For more information, check the post [Mixing Add Service Reference and WCF Web HTTP (a.k.a. REST) endpoint does not work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx).

Comment: Typically, endpoints defined with the `<webHttpBinding>`, `<webMessageEncoding>` or `<webHttp>` endpoint behavior.

Comment: Not if you're using a non-SOAP endpoint. In this case, the easiest way to test it would be to use any HTTP stack (`HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient`, `HttpClient`, etc.) to send GET/POST requests directly to it